# weird cakePHP isAuthorized() issue

Tags: php, cakephp, permissions, cakephp-1.3, acl

I'm using cakePHP's isAuthorized() function to check if a user is authorized to execute a controller action, but the weird problem I'm having is that the permissions on my other controller actions are blocked from the user as well. I'm only doing this:

```
function isAuthorized()
{
    $user_id_logged_in = $this->Auth->user('id');

    switch($this->action)
    {
        case: 'my_action':

        if($user_id_logged_in)
        {
             // check if user has access to execute controller action
             return $this->Acl->check(array(
                                'model' => 'MyModel', 'foreign_key' => $my_foreign_key), 
                                'controllers/MyController/'.$this->action);
        }
        else
        {
             return false;
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

I want to check if the logged user is authorized to execute the action `my_action`. But when I do this, the user loses permissions for the other actions in my controller as well. Any idea what is wrong with this?

Thank you

Comment: Where are you setting `$user_id_logged_in`?

Comment: $user_id_logged_in is just equal to `$this->Auth->user('id');`

Comment: From what I can tell from the documentation, the `check()` method takes 3 string parameters. `check($aro, $aco, $action = "*")`. You can see that [here](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/acl-component#method-AclComponentcheck).

Comment: I can see in the book your version.

Comment: Did you get this working? I also think maybe `MyModel` should be the name of your users model (`User` probably) and `$my_foreign_key` should be `$user_id_logged_in`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the fact that you're not returning any value at the end of `isAuthorized()`, so cake assumes it's `false` and therefore denying access to everything else.

Try adding a `return true;` at the end of the function if you're not interested in authorizing access to other functions (or alternatively, add them to the 'allow' list in Auth).